# Do I need a write buffer for socket in go?

Tags: sockets, tcp, go

Suppose I had a Tcp server in linux, it would create a new goroutine for a new connnection. When I want to write data to the tcp connection, should I do it just like this

```
conn.Write(data)
```

or do it in a goroutine especially for writing, like this

```
func writeRoutine(sendChan chan []byte){
      for {
       select {
       case  msg := <- sendChan :
          conn.Write(msg)
       }
      }
}
```

just in case that the network was busy.

In a short,  Did I need a write buffer in go just like in c/c++ when writing to a socket?

PS   maybe I didn't exclaim the problem clearly.

1     I talked of the server, meaning a tcp server runing in linux. It would create a new goroutine for a new connnection.  like this

```
   listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err.Error())
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := listener.AcceptTCP()
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        log.Debug("Accept a new connection ", conn.RemoteAddr())
        go handleClient(conn)
    }
```

2  I think my problem isn't much concerned with the code. As we know, when we use `size_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);` to write a socket fd in c/c++, for a tcp server, we need a write buffer for a socket in your code necessaryly, or maybe only some of the data is writen successfully. I mean, Do I have to do so in go ?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far, specifically what your server code looks like?  What problems do you anticipate, what problems have you observed?  Have you tried running your server with both ways of writing and seeing how each behaves?

Comment: Note that if you're doing standard HTTP stuff with `ListenAndServe` and `HandlerFunc`s, you should write to the `ResponseWriter` synchronously.  Seeing as you're writing directly to some connection object, maybe you're doing something lower level than a standard HTTP server?

Comment: You can use a buffered writer (`bufio.Writer`) if you want, but it's not really necessary.

Comment: I think what the OP is actually asking is if `conn.Write(msg)` will:  1. Write the whole `msg` or error ? or 2. Can write part of `msg` and thus need a loop or similar to write the entire `msg` ?

Comment: even if there is a  `bufio.Writer`, when the network is busy, the system send the data slowly, it will block , right?  so it'll still slow the latency .

Comment: @buzz if you're producing more data than you can send it to the client, you will buffer the data somewhere. What's the use of producing data faster than the client can consume it?

Answer (score 3):

You are actually asking two different questions here:

1) Should you use a goroutine per accepted client connection in my TCP server?
2) Given a []byte, how should I write to the connection?

For 1), the answer is yes. This is the type of pattern that go is most suited for. If you take a look at the source code for the [net/http](http://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1724), you will see that it spawns a goroutine for each connection.

As for 2), you should do the same that you would do in a c/c++ server: write, check how much was written and keep on writing until your done, always checking for errors. Here is a code snippet on how to do it:

```
func writeConn(data []byte) error {
    var start,c int
    var err error
    for {
      if c, err = conn.Write(data[start:]); err != nil {
          return err
      }
      start += c
      if c == 0 || start == len(data) {
          break
      }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have a `for` for write, contrary to C, in Go `Write` should write the whole slice or return an error. From docs: Write must return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p)

Answer (score 1):

> server [...] create a new goroutine for a new connnection

This makes sense because the handler goroutines can block without delaying the server's accept loop.

If you handled each request serially, any blocking syscall would essentially lock up the server for all clients.

> goroutine especially for writing

This would only make sense in use cases where you're writing either a really big chunk of data or to a very slow connection and you need your handler to continue unblocked, for instance.

Note that this is not what is commonly understood as a "write buffer".